# Can Insert and delete be done at the same time in oracle

Tags: oracle

Just curious to know.If two jobs are running one is inserting into a table and other is deleting some rows from the table. Can this be performed in parallel? The table contains 300 columns with 50GB data. Will it end in a deadlock if we do so?

Comment: Maybe they could deadlock on index blocks in some weird situations? But in principle, you can insert and delete at the same time.

Answer (score 1):

Given the fact you cannot remove records that have not been inserted, you can do insert and delete on the same table at the same time, but not on the same records. Hence, you cannot deadlock. You can lock though. You'll need to come up with something more complex, to deadlock Oracle.

Comment: Are you sure you cannot deadlock? Both inserts and deletes could need to try to update the same index blocks. If they do this in an unfortunate sequence, cannot there be a deadlock?

Comment: I understood that Oracle only locks blocks if ALL of the records are part of the lock itself. So, in that context, there's no lock of records that are OUTSIDE of the change itself, and thus - in this case - you cannot cause deadlock with insert and delete only.